# PHP Datables not showing any rows - Server side

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am having trouble getting Datables to work.

No-matter what I try, I am getting the issue that there is no data.
The message exactly is: "**No matching records found**".

I am using the correct format found [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/examples/integration/server_side.html) on the official website but it doesn't seem to want to load.

I am not using MYSQL so haven't include any SPP, but am just returning the array of address's inside an array then encoding it in JSON.

**In my frontend file, I am trying to load all address's from a certain router:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?=url('database/addresses');?>",
            "dataSrc": "",
        },
      'columnDefs': [{
          'targets': 1,
          'checkboxes': {
             'selectRow': true
          }
      }],
      'select': {
          'style':    'multi',
          'selector': 'td:first-child'
      },
      'order': [[5, 'desc']],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "input_address" },
            { "data": "destination_address" },
            { "data": "callback_url" },
            { "data": "dateCreated.date" },
            { "data": "id" }
        ],
        'colReorder': true
    });
} );
</script>
```

**My html table:**

```
 <form method="post" id="deleteMulti" class="ajax-multi" action="<?=url('XhPCrvFtQuE7gPP6/addresses/delete/selected');?>">
    <?= csrf() ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxl-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Addresses [ <?=$count;?> ]</h4>
                        <div class="right fr">
                            <button class="btn tooltip" style="display: inline;" name="deleteSelected" title="Delete Selected Addresses"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: black;"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="table" class="display">
                               <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" class="" id="checkAl"></th>
                                    <th>Input Address</th>
                                    <th>Output Address</th>
                                    <th>Callback Url</th>
                                    <th>Created</th>
                                    <th><i class="bi bi-archive-fill"></i></th>
                                  </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tfoot>
                                  <tr>
                                     <th></th>
                                     <th></th>
                                     <th></th>
                                     <th></th>
                                     <th></th>
                                     <th></th>
                                     <th></th>
                                  </tr>
                               </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**And in my database/addresses to load the database content:**

```
// This is used for when we need to load more address's to the admins /addresses page
public function getAddresses() {
    define('PAGE_NAME', 'Admin Addresses');

    // Skip 100 as we will start from the 100th row
    // We set the limit to 100 in Admin page so the page loads 100 much faster
    // We will push more and more using this function inside here for when they click load more
    $addresses = \r\table('addresses')->orderBy(array('index' => \r\desc('dateCreated')))->skip(100)->limit(100)->run($this->conn);
    $addresses = $addresses->toArray();

    $count = count($addresses);

    $theArr = array();

    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        $theArr[] = $address;
    }

    $final = array(
        'draw' => 1,
        'recordsTotal' => $count,
        'recordsFiltered' => $count,
        'data' => array_values($theArr)
    );

    if($count > 0) {
        echo json_encode($final, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My issue is that it keeps showing me:**
*No matching records found* eventhough I do have over 4k records in there.

Take a look at this picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJnd9.png)

**Take a look at the format of the json returned from my getAddresses()**:
[here](https://pastebin.com/tiRLtxWG)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question with more details or it will be closed and/or downvoted. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @biesior I just added more detail.